Cannot get cookies to my backend! I'm using MERN stack
Hello i'm working on this project solely for my learning purpose. So I have created the backend with some middlewares, routes etc.
This is my folder structure in backend
express.js server folder structure
Below is my index.js in backend server.
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoute.js';
import authRoutes from './routes/authRoute.js';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Middleware setup
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Routes
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOURL);
        console.log('MongoDB connected successfully');
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err.message);
    }
};

connectDB();

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    let statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    let message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";

    // Handle MongoDB duplicate key error
    if (err.code && err.code === 11000) {
        statusCode = 400;
        message = "Username or email already exists";
    }

    // Handle Mongoose validation errors
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        statusCode = 400;
        message = Object.values(err.errors).map(error => error.message).join(', ');
    }

    return res.status(statusCode).json({
        success: false,
        message,
        statusCode
    });
});


below is my userRoute.js
import express from 'express';
import { test, updateUser } from '../controllers/userController.js'
import { verifyToken } from '../utils/verifiedUser.js';


const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', test)
router.post('/update/:id',verifyToken, updateUser)

export default router;

below is my userController.js
import { errorHandler } from "../utils/error.js"
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs'
import User from '../models/userModel.js'

export const test = (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "api is working"
    })
}


//update user

export const updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    // if (req.user.id !== req.params.id) {
    //     return next(errorHandler(401, 'You can only update your accout'))
    // }
    try {
        if (req.body.password) {
            req.body.password = bcryptjs.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
        }
        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            $set: {
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                profilePicture: req.body.profilePicture
            }
        }, { new: true });
        const { password, ...rest } = updatedUser._doc;
        res.status(200).json(rest)


    } catch (error) {
        next(error)

    }

}

below is my verifiedUser.js in backend
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { errorHandler } from './error.js'


export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.cookies.access_token
    console.log(req)

    if (!token) return next(errorHandler(401, 'Access denied!'))

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return next(errorHandler(403, 'Token is not valid!'))

        req.user = user;
        next();
    })

}

and also i will provide you my authController.js as well to get full scope.
import User from '../models/userModel.js'
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs'
import { errorHandler } from '../utils/error.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'


export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
    const newUser = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
    try {
        await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message: "User created successfully" })

    } catch (error) {
        next(error)

    }
}

export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const validUser = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (!validUser) {
            return next(errorHandler(404, 'User not found'));
        }
        const validPassword = bcryptjs.compareSync(password, validUser.password);
        if (!validPassword) {
            return next(errorHandler(401, 'Invalid Credentials'));
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: validUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const { password: hashedPassword, ...rest } = validUser._doc;
        const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000); // 1 houre
        res.cookie('access_token', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: expiryDate,
            sameSite: 'None',
            secure: false
        }).status(200).json(rest);



    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}


export const google = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        if (user) {
            const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            const { password: hashedPassword, ...rest } = user._doc;
            const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000); // 1 hour
            res.cookie('access_token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                expires: expiryDate,
                sameSite: 'None',
                secure: false
            }).status(200).json(rest);

        } else {
            const generatedPW = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8)
            const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(generatedPW, 10)
            const newUser = new User({
                username: req.body.name.split(" ").join("").toLowerCase() + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)).toString(),
                email: req.body.email, password: hashedPassword,
                profilePicture: req.body.photo
            });

            await newUser.save();
            const token = jwt.sign({ id: newUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            const { password: hashedPassword2, ...rest } = newUser._doc;
            const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000); // 1 hour
            res.cookie('access_token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                expires: expiryDate,
                sameSite: 'None',
                secure: false
            }).status(200).json(rest);

        }

    } catch (error) {
        next(error)

    }

}

finally i will provide you my profile.jsx in front end
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
import { app } from "../firebase"
import toast from "react-hot-toast"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { updateUserStart, updateUserSuccess, updateUserFail } from "../redux/user/userSlice.js"
import axios from 'axios'


const Profile = () => {
    const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    const fileRef = useRef(null);
    const [image, setImage] = useState(undefined);
    const [imgLoading, setImgLoading] = useState(0);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
    const [imageError, setImageError] = useState(undefined);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(formData)


    useEffect(() => {
        if (image) {
            handleFileUpload(image)
        }
    }, [image])

    const handleFileUpload = async (image) => {
        const storage = getStorage(app);
        const fileName = new Date().getTime() + image.name;
        const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName)
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image)
        toast.promise(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                uploadTask.on(
                    'state_changed',
                    (snapshot) => {
                        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                        setImgLoading(Math.round(progress));
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        setImageError(error);
                        reject(error);

                    },
                    () => {
                        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                            setFormData({ ...formData, profilePicture: downloadURL });
                        })
                        resolve();
                    }
                );
            }),
            {
                loading: 'Uploading...',
                success: <b>Profile Photo Uploaded!</b>,
                error: <b>Could not save.</b>,
            }
        );
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            dispatch(updateUserStart());
            const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5555/api/user/update/${currentUser._id}`, formData, {
                withCredentials: true, // This ensures cookies are included
            });
            console.log(res);
            const data = await res.data;
            if (data.success === false) {
                dispatch(updateUserFail(data));
                return;
            }
            dispatch(updateUserSuccess(data));
            toast.success("Profile updated successfully!");
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(updateUserFail(error));
            console.log("Could not connect to server", error);
            // Extracting the error message
            const errorMessage = error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message
                : 'An error occurred';
            toast.error(errorMessage);
        }
    };



    return (
        <div className='p-3 max-w-lg mx-auto'>
            <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold text-center my-7'>Profile</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='flex flex-col gap-4'>
                <input type='file'
                    ref={fileRef}
                    hidden
                    accept='image/*'
                    onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />

                <img src={formData.profilePicture || currentUser.profilePicture}
                    alt='profile-picture'
                    className='h-24 w-24 self-center rounded-full cursor-pointer object-cover'
                    onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()} />

                <p className='text-sm self-center'>{imageError ?
                    (<span className='text-red-700'>Error Uploading Image (file size must be less than 5 MB)</span>)
                    : imgLoading > 0 && imgLoading < 100 ? (
                        <span className='text-slate-700'>{`Uploading Image... ${imgLoading}%`}</span>
                    ) : imgLoading === 100 ? '' : ''}</p>

                <input
                    defaultValue={currentUser.username}
                    type='text'
                    id='username'
                    placeholder='Username'
                    className='bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3'
                    onChange={handleChange} />

                <input
                    defaultValue={currentUser.email}
                    type='email' id='email'
                    placeholder='Email'
                    className='bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3'
                    onChange={handleChange} />

                <input type='password'
                    id='password'
                    placeholder='Password'
                    className='bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3'
                    onChange={handleChange} />

                <button className='bg-green-600 text-white rounded-lg p-3 uppercase hover:opacity-85 disabled:opacity-50'>Update</button>
            </form>
            <div className='flex justify-between py-2'>
                <span className='text-red-600 cursor-pointer'>Delete Account?</span>
                <span className='cursor-pointer'>Sign Out</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Profile

The thing is when I try to update user, it gives me access denied response. I tried to console.log the backend and found out that my req.cookies are coming as "  cookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
signedCookies: [Object: null prototype] {}"
But i tried to update user from postman and its worked very well. I try to use 'fetch' and also 'axios' post request but its not working when I send the request from front end.
